# How can I receive returnurl events from embedded app?

Tags: docusignapi

I sent envelope at embed app  without client_id. Then, I can check the envelope by email, and if I signed the envelope in the email, is there a way to get an event on the embed app?

```
public Map<String,Object> createRecipientView(Map<String,Object> recipientInfo) {
    Map<String,Object> result = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    // instantiate a new EnvelopesApi object
    EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();

    // set the url where you want the recipient to go once they are done signing
    RecipientViewRequest view = new RecipientViewRequest();
    //view.setReturnUrl("https://www.docusign.com");
    view.setReturnUrl(serverUrl+"/"+recipientInfo.get("usr_cls")+"/docusign/returnRecipientView.do?ds_usr_id="+recipientInfo.get("ds_usr_id") + "&docusign_id=" + recipientInfo.get("docusign_id")+ "&usr_cls=" + recipientInfo.get("usr_cls") + "&uiId=" +recipientInfo.get("uiId"));
    
    view.setAuthenticationMethod("email");

    // recipient information must match embedded recipient info we provided in step #2
    String email = (String)recipientInfo.get("email");
    String userName = (String)recipientInfo.get("usr_nm");
    String recipientId = (String)recipientInfo.get("recipient_id");
    String clientId = (String)recipientInfo.get("client_id");
    String envelopeId = (String)recipientInfo.get("envelope_id");
    view.setEmail(email);
    view.setUserName(userName);
    view.setRecipientId(recipientId);
    //view.seta
    //view.setClientUserId(clientId);

    // call the CreateRecipientView API
    ViewUrl recipientView;
    try {
        recipientView = envelopesApi.createRecipientView(accountId, envelopeId, view);
        
        log.info("Signing URL = " + recipientView.getUrl());
        result.put("url", recipientView.getUrl());
        result.put("result_status", "S");
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        log.error("error : " + e.toString());
        result.put("result_status", "F");
        result.put("result_message", e.toString());
    } 
    
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use webhook to get notifications about the envelope to your app.
You can read this [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-adding-webhooks-application) about it.
You can also look at this [code example](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/webhook-status).

Here is some C# code taken from [here](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-add-a-connect-webhook-to-your-envelopes):

```
EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
var eventNotification = new EventNotification();
\\ Set up the endpoint URL to call (it must be using HTTPS and at least TLS1.1 or higher)
eventNotification.Url = "https:\\myapp.somedomain.com";
\\ DocuSign will retry on failure if this is set
eventNotification.RequireAcknowledgment = "true";
\\ This would send the documents together with the event to the endpoint
eventNotification.IncludeDocuments = "true";
\\ Allows you to see this in the DocuSign Admin Connect logs section
eventNotification.LoggingEnabled = "true";
var envelopeEvents = new List<EnvelopeEvent>();
\\ In this case we only add a single envelope event, when the envelope is completed. You can also add events for recipients
envelopeEvents.Add(new EnvelopeEvent { EnvelopeEventStatusCode = "completed", IncludeDocuments = "true" });        
eventNotification.EnvelopeEvents = envelopeEvents;
envelopeDefinition.EventNotification = eventNotification;
```

Comment: I will apply webhook and check. Thank you for your answer.